# Function name macro in C++

Tags: c++, macros

I have a c++ macro that looks like this

```
#define lua_tpushstring(L,n,f) \
            (lua_pushstring(L, n), lua_pushstring(L, f))
```

I want to modify it so it works like this

```
#define lua_tpush(TYPE,L,n,f) \
            (lua_pushstring(L, n), lua_pushTYPE(L, f))

lua_tpush(boolean, L, "a", true);
lua_tpush(string, L, "a", "");
```

What is the simple change?

Comment: Have you considered using templates instead?

Comment: Agree with sbi. DRY principle; if I'm pushing `true` I don't need to repeat myself and tell the compiler that I'm pushing a `bool`. But you don't even need templates; overloading is sufficient. You'd need functions though (macro's don't overload) : `void LuaClass::push(std::string n, bool f) { lua_pushstring(this->L, n); lua_pushboolean(this->L, f); }` etc.

Comment: @MSalters: Indeed, since the functionality is so trivial, overloading might, in this case, be just as good. generally, however, if you need many similar implementations, templates are better, since you don't have to copy the code over and over.

Answer (score 6):

[Token concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html):

```
#define lua_tpush(TYPE,L,n,f)  (lua_pushstring(L, n), lua_push##TYPE(L, f))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put `##` before `TYPE`.

```
#define lua_tpush(TYPE,L,n,f) \
            (lua_pushstring(L, n), lua_push##TYPE(L, f))
                     ^^^^^^ did you wanted ##TYPE here
```